# Casting subtype fails

Tags: dart

```
class A {
  void hello() {
    print('world');
  }
}

class B extends A {
  @override
  void hello() {
    print('StackOverflow');
  }
}
```

*`(A() as B).hello();` results in `type 'A' is not a subtype of type 'B' in type cast`.*

Comment: `(Animal() as Dog).bark();` What should happen when `Animal()` returns a `Cat`?

Comment: The problem is not that you're calling `.hello()`. `A() as B` is the problem. A can't be "as B" since A does not extend B. With the other way around `B() as A`, there will exist a `virtual method table` for B with the A it extends which can be used to look up the methods B (and its A) has access to.

Comment: If you really need to do that transformation, then use a lower level language like C++. But even C++ discourages this in the STL. Those languages let you cast anything to anything, which is what you are intending to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I don't know Dart.

You can't do this kind of cast because it might result in function calls or field accesses that aren't well defined.

I'll change your example to demonstrate:

```
class A {
    void hello() {
         print('world');
    }
}


class B extends A {
    @override
    void hello() {
        print('StackOverflow');
    }
    void hello2() {
        print('Is Great!');
    }
}
```

Now if you do `(A() as B).hello2();` what should Dart do? This isn't really obvious, so it doesn't allow you to do that. Going the other way isn't an issue since `B` inherits all stuff from `A`.

```
class A {
    void hello() {
         print('world');
    }
}


class B extends A {
    @override
    void hello() {
        print('StackOverflow');
    }
}

class C extends A {
    @override
    void hello() {
        print('Hello');
    }
}
```

Another issue is a value that has type `A` may be a different subtype of `A` like `C`

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot: It can't add additional methods that don't exist. `A` does not have `Hello2()`, so there's nothing to add. You can't invent functionality in `A` that does not exist in `A`. Casting in the other direction works because `B` inherits functionality from it's ancestor, but `A` can't inherit anything from `B`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot: You can't. The data is not available to `A`. Consider it this way: A man can pass his genes on to his son, who inherits his eye color, facial characteristics, and even his name (*Fred Jr*). But that father cannot walk into a barbershop and say *Call me Junior and give my son a haircut*, because the barber can't cut the son's hair via the father's head. If you have a need to do what you're asking, your classes are designed incorrectly and you should consider a redesign.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot the usual day to do what (I think you are asking) is via overriding in subclasses. Have default behavior in the parent (`A`) and override it to do what you want in `B`

Comment: You can use an adapter pattern, or just wrap the A in something new

Answer (score 1):

The way casting works is you can only go from a more specific type, B in this case, to a more general type, A. Your creating an instance of A, but A is not B.

Answer (score 0):

Dart generally allows you to down-cast from a super-type to a sub-type because the value might actually be of the sub-type.

```
Animal animal = Cat();
if (something) animal = Dog();
...
Cat cat = animal as Cat; // Allowed, the animal may be a cat.
```

However, Dart 2 disallows down-casts in a few cases where it is *obvious* (even to the compiler) that the cast will always fail at run-time. That's what you are hitting here: `(A() as B)`. The `A()` calls a generative constructor, so the compiler knows that the type of that expressions is *exactly* `A` (and not any proper sub-type of `A`). So, it knows that casting that to `B` will *always* fail at run-time, and for your own protection, it disallows the program entirely. Hence, a compile-time error.